# Swift IBDesignable UIButton Class - Change Width on didRotate

Tags: swift

I have an IBDesignable Class for my submit button.

I use a percent for the width based on the size of the screen. No issues.

But how do I change the width on a didRotate?

Here is the Class:

```
@IBDesignable
class SubmitButton : UIButton {

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupBtn()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupBtn()
    }

    func setupBtn() {

        var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.75

        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){

            if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {      
                width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.5
            } else {                  
                width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.6              
            }


        }

        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone){

            if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
                width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.5
            } else {
                width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.75
            }

        }

        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true

        tintColor = .white
        backgroundColor = .green

    }

}
```

so I tried to do something like this to detect rotation.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {

        width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.75

    } else {

        width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width  * 0.5

    }


    submitBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true


}
```

nothing happens and the button totally disappears.  this is the Xcode error.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000088fb40 myPerformance.SubmitButton:0x7fa2a5741cd0'Update'.width == 0.667   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000088c620 myPerformance.SubmitButton:0x7fa2a5741cd0'Update'.width == 200   (active)>"
)
```

Is it possible to add the didRotate to this class or do I need to manually add a width to the buttons and take it out of the class?

What is best way adjust the width to adapt for all the iPhone, iPad, Landscape and Portrait options?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to modify the `constant` property of the existing constraint rather than adding an additional, conflicting, constraint

Comment: not sure how to do that, sorry.  I am not a coder - just an amateur.  thanks.